# Program executing incorrectly

Tags: c++

I wrote a tiny program in C++ that is supposed to get 2 integers from the user and print out the sum of those two integers like so;

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int a;
    int b;
    int c = a + b;

    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;

    std::cout << c;

    return 0;
}
```

But everytime I run the program, I'm able to type the two integers but the resulting answer is always `65538`:

```
> 1
> 1
65538
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Doesn't your compiler raised any warning?

Comment: @user3670002: it's *unnecessary* to include a screenshot. including a screenshot is also *problematic* for folks accessing SO through a low bandwidth connection (that includes myself at the moment). instead, consider copying and pasting the text in the console window. if it's unclear how to do that, try to google it.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: comment above is also to you. OP desired and intended it, but you delivered it. hrmpf. anyway, if that really is Windows Vista, then I very very much recommend upgrading to Windows 7 (if possible). i had to accept Windows 8.1 on latest laptop and it was not good compared to Windows 7, but can be made halfway usable by e.g. installing various 3rd party software. Also I recommned Visual Studio or, if that's too large, Code::Blocks, instead of Dev-Cpp. Less problems.

Comment: Languages such as C++ execute statements within a thread sequentially (or more accurately, they behave as if they execute sequentially). You can't expect the statement `int c = a + b` to do anything meaningful because the user hasn't been asked for the values of `a` and `b` yet at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to...

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;

    c = a + b;       //let c be the sum of a and b
    std::cout << c;  //print c

    return 0;
}
```

`c` appears as 65538 because `c` was not initialize. A random garbage value was assigned to `c`.
Most importantly, you did not assign the values of `a + b` to `c` before printing, that is why you are getting the garbage value of `c`.

In other words, If you initialize your variables to (say 0) as such:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
```

You would get `0` instead of `65538` because that is the original value of `c` before you assign any new values to it.

I hope I made it simple enough for you to understand what went wrong.

Comment: More precisely, the values of `a` and `b` are undefined, so the result of accessing them is undefined behaviour. The `+` operator may as well crash, or do anything else, not just write a random value into `c`.

Answer (score 5):

Place statement

```
int c = a + b;
```

after vstatements

```
std::cin >> a;
std::cin >> b;
```

At first you hace to enter values for variables a and b and only after store the sum in variable c.

Answer (score 5):

The statement

```
int c = a + b;
```

is not an assertion about a relationship between the values.

It's just a computation to be done, computing `c` from (presumed) already known values `a` and `b`.

As such, place it *after* the input statements.

---

To get warnings about using variables with *indeterminate* values (not initialized), with Visual C++ use option `/W4`, and with g++ use option `-Wall` plus an optimization option such as just `-O`.

Example of the g++ behavior:

```
[H:\dev\test\0107]
> g++ foo.cpp

[H:\dev\test\0107]
> g++ -Wall foo.cpp

[H:\dev\test\0107]
> g++ -Wall -O foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:7:15: warning: 'a' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     int c = a + b;
               ^
foo.cpp:7:15: warning: 'b' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

[H:\dev\test\0107]
> _
```

Comment: Just so it's clear in my head, because somebody else corrected me recently, isn't indeterminate != uninitialized? As in, a and b are initialized, but have indeterminate value? (ub still applies)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: That's a very fine point, but yes. You can initialize a variable with its own before-that-uninitialized indeterminate value. It's UB to do that. Barring such abuse of the language indeterminate is in practice the same as uninitialized. I can't think of a better formulation in the answer so for now I'm just keeping it, but thanks!

Comment: K, thanks. I'll also keep using "uninitialized", but in my head I'll know that's not pedantically accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting`65538`, a garbage value, is that you are performing operation `c = a + b;` before reading the value from user. Since `a` and `b` are uninitialized, this operation takes the previously stored values at `a` abd `b` in memory. This invokes undefined behavior.
You need to palace the line `int c = a + b;` after reading `a` and `b`.

```
std::cin >> a;
std::cin >> b;
int c = a + b;
```